# When rebasing off master, should I add and commit first?

Tags: git, rebase

I want to catch up with master, e.g. `git rebase master`

Should I `git add` and `git commit` my current changes before or after the rebase against master?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to rebase with local, uncommited changes, you get:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes. Please commit or stash them.
```

Therefore you can only rebase if you do not have local changes,
so you need either to commit before, use `git checkout -f` to remove local
changes or using `git stash` to save your changes (if you are e.g. on a side project).

I recommend committing all your changes, since then `git` can rebase them on the
new master which saves you usually much time.